# Add draggable marker and get position openlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap-plugins, openstreetmap

Here is my code and i want to drag the marker and get the position can any one help me in this? i am using it in phonegap. i am getting the current location using geolocation plugin and plotting that on the openstreet map but having difficulty in moving the marker.

```
    <html>
   <body>
   <div id="mapdiv"></div>
  <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var storage = window.localStorage;
  // onSuccess Callback
    // This method accepts a Position object, which contains the
    // current GPS coordinates
    //
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
      alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
        'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
        'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
        'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
        'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
        'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
        'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
        'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
      map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
      map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

      var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude)
      .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
            );

      var zoom=16;

      var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
      map.addLayer(markers);


      markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

      map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
    };

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
    function onError(error) {
      alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
        'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    </script>
    <script>

    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Did you already take a look at the [drag example](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/drag-feature.html)?

Comment: Yes i have looked that but the issue is with marker, I am not able to show the marker there.

Comment: i have used the example code, No map is shown when i run it in simulator. The same problem is occurring when i use the leaflet plugin